# Hibernate HQL error : Path expression ends in a composite value

Tags: java, hibernate

I am getting below error when I execute the below piece of code using hibernate.
Error:
Path expression ends in a composite value:

Code/java method:

```
MatioFunctionExpression MatioFunctionExpression = null;
MatioFunctionExpressionId MatioFunctionExpressionId = null;
try {
    MatioFunctionExpression = new MatioFunctionExpression();

    MatioFunctionExpressionId = new MatioFunctionExpressionId();
    MatioFunctionExpressionId.setMatioFunctionId(MatioFunctionId);
    MatioFunctionExpressionId.setExpressionId(expressionId);

    MatioFunctionExpression.setId(MatioFunctionExpressionId);
    List<MatioFunctionExpression> instance
        = (List<MatioFunctionExpression>) template.find("from MatioFunctionExpression MatioFunctionExpression where MatioFunctionExpression.id = ?",
                                                        MatioFunctionExpression.getId());
    logger.debug("get successful");
    if (instance.size() > 0) {
        MatioFunctionExpression = instance.get(0);
    } else {
        logger.debug("Lookup of id [" + expressionId + "] is not found in MatioFunctionExpression table");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your entity is using a composite key, I'm not sure that it is possible to write an `HQL` query like that. Try adding each parameter of the key separately. Something like that :

```
RatioFunctionExpression ratioFunctionExpression = null;
RatioFunctionExpressionId ratioFunctionExpressionId = null;
try {
    ratioFunctionExpression = new RatioFunctionExpression();

    List<Object> params = new ArrayList<Object>();
    params.add(ratioFunctionId);
    params.add(expressionId);

    List<RatioFunctionExpression> instance
        = (List<RatioFunctionExpression>) template.find("from RatioFunctionExpression ratioFunctionExpression where ratioFunctionExpression.id.ratioFunctionId = ? and ratioFunctionExpression.id.expressionId = ?",
                                                        params.toArray());
    logger.debug("get successful");
    if (instance.size() > 0) {
        ratioFunctionExpression = instance.get(0);
    } else {
        logger.debug("Lookup of id [" + expressionId + "] is not found in RatioFunctionExpression table");
    }
```